# How to reverse engineer binary file formats for compatibility purposes

Tags: reverse-engineering, binaryfiles

I am working of a file preparation software to enable translators work easily and efficiently on a wide range of file formats.

As far as text-based formats (xml, php, resource files,...) are concerned, my small preparation utility works fine, but a major problem for most translators is to handle all kinds of proprietary binary formats (Framemaker, Publisher, Quark...).

These files are rarely requested and need to be opened in expensive applications (few freelance can afford to buy $20,000 worth of software just to handle a few projects per year), and even then it is not convenient to work directly in those applications anyway.

I would like to be able to read these files and extract the text in such a way that it can be translated and then re-imported in the original application with minimal effort, or even better, to recreate a valid native binary file.

Does that sound doable?

Where can I find more information on handling binary file formats and are there useful tools for these kind of jobs (besides regular hex editors)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course reverse engineering is possible, but without format specs it will take a lot of work. I would look at the return on effort regarding supporting these 'rarely requested, very expensive' formats. You may be better off spending that effort improving the core functionality of your app.

Another angle is to contact the companies with these formats, explain your goal, explain that it helps their product, and if they don't see you as competition they might be willing to help.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you want to reverse engineer them - but since these may be propriety file formats you are looking at a very steep curve trying to decode them...

Some (as I have written some propritety formats for interal use before) have specific methods and objects written into them that serve some alternative process than the file contents themselves.  Stuff that would prove the new file is illegal.

Just my 2 cents and I am no lawyer =>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could pick a cheaper application which has import features for QuarkXPress. For example InDesign should be able to read Quark documents. Then use the importing application to export to whatever format you need - maybe with a help of plug-in.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am not trying to figure out a cheaper workaround for myself, I am trying to develop a file preparation software to provide an alternative for translators having to deal with these formats.